# How to Change Table Background with tableGrob in GridExtra

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

I have this Gridmesh in the Background of my plottet table. How do i Change the Background other then with theme

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHpd5.jpg

```
cor.t=mydata

tt3 <- ttheme_minimal(
base_size = 8,
core=list(bg_params = list(fill = paste(substr(HeaderFarbe[n+1],
start = 1, stop = 7),"4D",sep=""),
col=HeaderFarbe[n+1]),
fg_params=list(fontface=3)),
colhead=list(fg_params=list(col=HeaderFarbe[n+1], fontface=4L)),
rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col="red", fontface=3L)))

plot(tableGrob(cor.t ,theme=tt3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no background if you use `grid::grid.draw(tableGrob())` (or `grid.table()` directly). `plot.gtable`, adding the grey background, is meant for debugging only.